# Add custom admin menu item for pages using a certain template

Tags: pages, wp-admin, page-template, admin-menu

I am looking to add a new, custom menu item to the WordPress admin sidebar that displays pages that use a certain template. For example: a group of pages uses the template called "Retailer Sendout" (page-retailer-sendout.php) would be displayed below the default "Pages" top-level menu item.

I have tried the following URL combinations, but none of them have worked so far.

- http://domain.test/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page&page_template=page-retailer-sendout
- http://domain.test/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=pagetemplate=page-retailer-sendout
- http://domain.test/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page&page_template=retailer_sendout

I have also tested some admin menu customization plugins, but they do not offer the ability to link to pages with a specific template name.

I am comfortable with adding a custom function to the theme's functions.php file, but I do not know where to start.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is what you want:

[image: Sample Output]

... you can do it like so:

**Step #1: Add the custom menu item (`Retailer Sendout`).**

```php
function add_retailer_sendout_admin_menu() {
    $slug = 'edit.php?post_type=page&template=page-retailer-sendout.php';

    add_menu_page( 'Retailer Sendout', 'Retailer Sendout', 'edit_pages', $slug,
        '', 'dashicons-admin-page', 19 );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_retailer_sendout_admin_menu' );
```

**Notes:**

1. I'm using [`add_menu_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/) to add the menu (which is a top-level menu) with the permission `edit_pages` and the icon `dashicons-admin-page` — just check the reference for more details about the syntax and parameters, but the position (the 7th parameter) is set to `19` which would put the menu *above the `Pages`* menu.
2. If you change the *name* of the query string `template`, you also need to change it in *both* steps #2 and #3 below. But if you change just the *value*, you only need to also change it in step #2 below.

**Step #2: Highlight the menu item (this adds `current` to the item/`li` `class`) after you clicked on the link.**

Because the 'Pages' and 'Pages » All Pages' menu *slug* is `edit.php?post_type=page`, we *have to* make sure WordPress doesn't override the `$parent_file` (i.e. the above `$slug` value) as set in `highlight_retailer_sendout_admin_menu()` below, so the `fix_admin_parent_file_override()`, although is a hack/trick, is needed — you could just add the CSS class `current` to the `Retailer Sendout` menu, but you'd end up with two/three highlighted menus..

And even though I'm not changing the CSS `class`, you can use the function to add your custom class(es) and/or remove/edit existing ones. Also, just so you know, the `$menu` is an array of the *top-level* menus *only*, so I use the `$submenu` to access the sub-menus. I also use `$pagenow` because at this point, the current screen (see [`get_current_screen()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_screen/)) hasn't been setup yet.

```php
function fix_admin_parent_file_override( $menu ) {
    global $pagenow, $submenu;

    // If we're NOT on the edit.php page, do nothing.
    if ( ! is_admin() || 'edit.php' !== $pagenow ) {
        return $menu;
    }

    // Same as in the above add_retailer_sendout_admin_menu().
    $slug = 'edit.php?post_type=page&template=page-retailer-sendout.php';

    // We have to make sure the $parent_file is not overriden (by WordPress) to
    // the 'Pages' menu.
    if ( ! empty( $_GET['template'] ) &&
        'page-retailer-sendout.php' === $_GET['template'] ) {
        // Change the 'Pages' URL.
        $menu[20][2] .= '&template=';
        $submenu[ $menu[20][2] ] = $submenu['edit.php?post_type=page'];

        // Change the 'All Pages' URL.
        $submenu[ $menu[20][2] ][5][2] = $menu[20][2];

        unset( $submenu['edit.php?post_type=page'] );
    }

    return $menu;
}
add_filter( 'add_menu_classes', 'fix_admin_parent_file_override' );
```

And next, we set the `$parent_file` — note that in the above, we *don't* set the `$parent_file`, we only make sure WordPress doesn't override the value afterwards. So for this part, we should use the [`parent_file` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/parent_file/):

```php
function highlight_retailer_sendout_admin_menu( $parent_file ) {
    // Make sure the PARENT slug is the one for the 'Pages' / 'All Pages' menu.
    if ( 'edit.php?post_type=page' === $parent_file &&
        ( ! empty( $_GET['template'] ) )            &&
        // ..and make sure the template being queried is page-retailer-sendout.php.
        'page-retailer-sendout.php' === $_GET['template'] )
    {
        // Return the $slug value as in the above add_retailer_sendout_admin_menu()
        return 'edit.php?post_type=page&template=page-retailer-sendout.php';
    }
    return $parent_file;
}
add_filter( 'parent_file', 'highlight_retailer_sendout_admin_menu' );
```

**Step #3: Filter the pages by the template.**

The template name is stored in a private metadata named `_wp_page_template`, so we filter the posts/pages query by adding a *meta query* for that metadata.

And we're using the [`pre_get_posts` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) which also runs on the public side of the site, so we perform checks like `is_admin()` and [`is_main_query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/is_main_query/) to prevent messing with other `WP_Query` calls (or posts requests).

```php
function filter_admin_pages_by_template( $query ) {
    // Make sure we run the filter only on the admin side of the site (wp-admin)
    // and that the query is the main query.
    if ( is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() &&
        ( ! empty( $_GET['template'] ) )       &&
        // ..and also, check if we're on the edit.php?post_type=page screen.
        'edit-page' === get_current_screen()->id )
    {
        $meta_query = (array) $query->get( 'meta_query' );
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'   => '_wp_page_template',
            'value' => $_GET['template'],
        );
        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_admin_pages_by_template' );
```

And actually, you can use the code to filter any templates.. not just the `page-retailer-sendout.php` as in the question. :)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and answer to my question. The code is working almost as needed with one catch. Is there any way to have an alias for "Retailer Sendout" appear above the "Pages" parent?

Comment: So you want to have *both* `Pages -> Retailer Sendout` and a *top-level* menu item named `Retailer Sendout`? Or is it just the top-level menu? Either way, is the top-level menu going to have sub-menus?

Comment: Just a top-level menu item would be preferred. There would no need for second-level menu items as "Retailer Sendout" is a single page template type.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I was just confused on that 'alias'.. :) But okay then, I'll revise the answer.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I work with Joomla more than WordPress and an alias is used for menu items if more than one are required to be displayed on a site.

Comment: And I, have forgotten pretty much everything about Joomla development... :) So I have revised the answer, but step #3 remains the same. Also, *In the `fix_admin_parent_file_override()`, the `$slug` is not needed. I just forgot to remove it.* Sorry!

Comment: Thanks for the code adjustments. They work just as expected. Your help was greatly appreciated.